# Why does copy/paste put the x and y at a negative value?

Tags: fireworks

I often do a screen capture and paste it into Fireworks.
I always have to change the x and y values to 0 because they're always negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this happens if the image is larger than my window. If you make sure you're zoomed out until you can see the whole canvas first, the item should paste into the correct position.